# How do I run a Tasker task from inside Llama?

Tags: tasker, llama

I want to run a tasker task from inside of Llama.  If possible, with a parameter.  Setting up intents is extremely painful, and not user friendly.  I'm fine with intents if there is a simple, consistent way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A user-friendly way (as of Nov 2016) is to:

- Create a llama event
- "Add Action"
  ** "Run App Shortcut"
  ** "Task Shortcut"
  ** (shows list of Tasker tasks -- pick one)
- Test it

You could create several tasker tasks, if your number of parameters is limited to a specific subset (e.g. location profile names).

Not sure how to add parameters, or how android intents work.